# Calling LinqPad 7 from Visual Studio C# Project

Tags: c#, linqpad, linqpad7

I am trying to call `LinqPad` `query` from `C#`. Unfortunately, the code below does not work; the `result` is `null` as if nothing got returned by the `script`. I don't see any example of how to do this online. Any direction would be appreciated.

This is the `LinqPad` code for the query. It is saved as a `C# Statement`:

```
string Main(string message)
{
    "testing".Dump();
    return message.ToUpper();
}
```

This is the code in `C#` code in a `Visual Studio Project` `Console Application` that attempts to call the query:

```
using System;

using LINQPad;


namespace ConsoleAppLinqPad
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pathToQuery = @"C:\Users\synct\OneDrive\Documents\LINQPad Queries\";
            string script = "samplequery.linq";
            var wholePath = pathToQuery + script;

            using (var query = Util.Compile(wholePath))
            {
                var results = query.Run(QueryResultFormat.Text, "hello world").ReturnValueAsync.GetAwaiter();

                while (!results.IsCompleted)
                    ;


                var result = results.GetResult();
                Console.WriteLine(result.Dump());  // prints "HELLO WORLD?"
                
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "the code below does not work"?

Comment: I updated the original post. If there is a working sample I would love to see it.

Comment: Are you aware of [lprun](https://www.linqpad.net/lprun.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, but how is that different than what I am trying to do here? I don't reallly want to instantiate a process unless the above strategy doesn't work

Comment: Running a .NET console app will create a process too. I don't know your requirements, but if you're just trying to run a LINQPad script then lprun.exe is the  most straightforward.

Comment: I see. Is there an example of how to instantiate lprun and pass it a query to execute, then gather the result from C#?

Comment: The doc I linked to has all I know about it and more. I guess you could use Process.Start and redirect output but it seems a round-about way to execute a script. I suppose it is not practical to just put the code in a proper .NET application?

Comment: I have provided an example of the lprun usage in my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2699466/5045688

Answer (score 2):

There is a `LPRun7-x64.exe` shipped with LinqPad (ARM64 and x86 versions are available as well) which allows to run LinqPad from a console. But you can also run it from a process.

With the example below you could run your `samplequery.linq` like:

```
string pathToQuery = @"C:\Users\synct\OneDrive\Documents\LINQPad Queries\";
string script = "samplequery.linq";
RunLpQuery(@$"{pathToQuery}{script}");
```

**Example:**

```
void Main()
{
    RunLpQuery(@$"{AppPath}\Hello.linq");
}

public string AppPath =>
#if LINQPAD
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Util.CurrentQueryPath);
#else
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType()).Location);
#endif

// Linqpad 4+5: "LPRun.exe"
// LinqPad 6:   "LPRun6.exe"
// Linqpad 7:   "LPRun7-x64.exe"  
public const string LpRunName = "LPRun7-x64.exe";

object RunLpQuery(string query)
#if LINQPAD
    => Util.Run(query, QueryResultFormat.Html).Dump();
#else
    => StartProcess(@$"{Util.LINQPadFolder}\{LpRunName}", AppPath, query);
#endif

bool StartProcess(string fileName, string workingDir, string arguments,
                  bool hidden = false)
{
    var p = new Process();
    var args = p.StartInfo;
    if (hidden)
    {
        args.CreateNoWindow = true; args.UseShellExecute = false; // runs hidden
    }
    args.FileName = fileName;
    args.WorkingDirectory = workingDir;
    args.Arguments = arguments;
    var result = p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    return result;
}
```

Hello.linq:

```
void Main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        "Hello World!".Dump(); Thread.Sleep(500);
    }   
}
```

**Note** that the example uses conditional compilation: Through `#if LINQPAD` statements it can run directly inside of LinqPad itself, showing the output of the called Hello example in the result windows, or outside in a Visual Studio project.

---

Details about the parameters for lprun can be found [here](http://www.linqpad.net/lprun.aspx). And if you just want to use LinqPad's extensions in the context of your VS project, then have a look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414214/linqpad-in-visual-studio/38199055#38199055).

Comment: Weird people on SO. I upvoted so at least it's a 0 again.