# Target build term of XCode in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I've do a small project, my application will release 2 version, each version contain different image resource, different Application setting file. I known that in the XCode, it's have a term call Target which allow developer config some folder which want to build for each version.

Can Visual Studio do the same thing like XCode?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is solution build configurations, check this link out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is a good example of including a reference for a specific configuration.
[Visual Studio Project: How to include a reference for one configuration only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493749/visual-studio-project-how-to-include-a-reference-for-one-configuration-only)

You will need to research the topic a bit, but here is how to get started:
1. Open your Solution
2. In solution explorer right click the solution
3. Select Configuration Manager
4. Create a new configuration or modify one of the default ones.

Example of a solution with many build configurations:
  [image]

Each of these configurations have custom configs and some have different references based on the configuration.

Comment: Thank for fast respone :) I'll check your link and feedback soon.

Comment: No problem, I actually had to set this up recently for a solution we wanted to be able to build with different references and configs. So it was fresh on my mind.  For the app.configs we are using slowcheetah for config transforms based on the configuration being built.

Comment: I read your link but still confuse and don't know what exactly what to do to make my project work :(

Comment: I added a small example, just know that it is possible, you may need to do some additional research on the topic.

Comment: Thank you for you support! I don't know where to set the Reference for each version, I'll do more research about this topic. Thanks again :)