# Conditional conditional symbol definition in a .csproj file

Tags: xml, msbuild, conditional-statements, csproj

I am an experienced C# developer, but a complete beginner when it comes to MSBuild, and now I have a .csproj file containing the following XML snippet:

```xml
<Choose>
  <When Condition=" $(UseSimulatedResx) == true ">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);SIMRESX</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
    ... does something else ...
  </When>
</Choose>
```

Is there way any anyone can explain me how and when the excerpt above should work? Where and when should I issue this UseSimulatedResx?

What I have to do is try to let SIMRESX be a conditional compilation symbol for a project in my solution so as to enable some features of our massive product.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UseSimulatedResx` can be set in one of the following ways:

- as an environment variable
- as the parameter when invoking msbuild (e.g. `/p:UseSimulatedResx=true`)
- in a PropertyGroup (e.g.

  `<PropertyGroup>
    <UseSimulateResx>true</UseSimulateResx>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>`

)

If you invoke msbuild with `/v:diag` (e.g. `msbuild myProj.csproj /v:diag`) you will get the diagnostic output that shows everything MSBuild does plus all the variable values.